# Краткое доказательство метода Крамера

Tags: математика, линейная-алгебра

На английской версии сайта увидел краткое доказательство правила Крамера и никак не могу его понять. Пожалуйста, дайте совет - что автор имеет в виду? Спасибо [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам для конкретно 2x2 пояснить или нужно общее пояснение, для NxN?

Comment: Думаю, что 2x2 подойдет!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем случае смотрите [тут](http://www.cleverstudents.ru/systems/Cramers_method.html), например.

А так - все просто. Итак, есть исходная система

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Искусственно расширим векторы (x,y) и (p,q) до показанных матриц:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видим, сами уравнения не изменились, а добавление (0 1) и (b d) привело просто к тождеству, так что ничего нового мы не добавили (ни новых корней, ни новых условий на корни).

Далее, поскольку определитель произведения матриц равен произведению определителей, а также просто находя определитель расширенной матрицы, который равен просто `x`, мы находим, что

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

откуда очевидным образом получаем `x` как отношение двух определителей.

Для `y` все то же самое, только расширенная матрица имеет вид

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот и все.

Answer (score 2):

1. По свойству определителя det(AB)=det(A)det(B)
2. det ([x,0][y,1])=x*1-y*0=x
3. Dx=D1=> x=D1/D

Автор переводит вектор столбец (x,y) в матрицу, чтобы использовать свойство определителя.